# When I try to create any Livewire component I always obtain «syntax error, unexpected token "[", expecting "{"»

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-livewire

When I run

```
 php artisan make:livewire mycomponent
```

I always obtain:

```
   ParseError 

  syntax error, unexpected token "[", expecting "{"

  at app/Http/Livewire/Mycomponent.php:5
      1▕ <?php
      2▕ 
      3▕ namespace App\Http\Livewire;
      4▕ 
  ➜   5▕ use App\Models\[Normally the Last Word of the Namespace in Singular, for example «User»]
      6▕ use Livewire\Component;
      7▕ 
      8▕ class Mycomponent extends Component
      9▕ {

      +1 vendor frames 
  2   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass()

      +1 vendor frames 
  4   [internal]:0
      Livewire\LivewireComponentsFinder::Livewire\{closure}()
```

Then, the files are created, but they contain garbage, piece of code of other components, instead of a fresh void component.

Does someone know why is not working the creation of the components?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Have you changed the stubs?

Answer (score 0):

As Qirel suggested in his comment, the problem was with the stubs. I deleted all the stubs related to Livewire, and it worked again.

Thank you very much @Qirel!